# Saída de "while" em preenchimento de listas

Tags: python, lista, while

Preciso fazer um código que use `while` e listas, que tenha como objetivo o usuário realizar cadastro de um número indeterminado de pessoas enquanto quiser e coloque 0 para finalizar e mostrar na tela a lista criada.

[É o exercício 5](https://medium.com/reflex%C3%A3o-computacional/7-exerc%C3%ADcios-while-b4d7d5354b97).

Assim eu fiz mas não consigo fazer parar quando digita 0:

```
print('Digite 0 para terminar o cadastro!')

cont = 1
lista = []
n = ()
while n != 0:
  n = (lista.append(input('Funcionário {}: '.format(cont))))
  cont += 1

print(lista)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está adicionando isso em uma lista e tentando guardar o resultado da lista e não o valor digitado em uma variável. Isso não dá certo. O `append()` retorna `None` e não o valor inserido.

Você deve pegar o valor e testar se é o momento de sair (digitou 0) e só se não for é que deve adicionar na lista.

Já que o teste de saída ocorre dentro do laço não tem porque testar isso no `while`, o que simplifica tudo.

```
print('Digite 0 para terminar o cadastro!')
cont = 1
lista = []
while True:
    n = input('Funcionário {}: '.format(cont))
    if n == "0":
        break
    lista.append(n)
    cont += 1
print(lista)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/NOdr8S). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ExitNumberpy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/ExitNumber.py).